# Twig array construction from an existing array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, twig

I need some help with this array I can't figure out how can I create a multidimensional array according to some array values.

I have a normal array, let's say with the following dump output:

```
array(
  [0] => ("id" => "421", "name" => "element 1", "TYPE" => "1")
  [1] => ("id" => "422", "name" => "element 2", "TYPE" => "2")
  [2] => ("id" => "423", "name" => "element 3", "TYPE" => "2")
  [3] => ("id" => "424", "name" => "element 4","TYPE" => "1")
)
```

I need to create a multidimensional array according to "TYPE" key. if TYPE = 1 this array should contain all arrays which have "TYPE" == 2 until the next array will be found with the TYPE == 1 the output should be something like this:

```
array(
  [421] => array(
    "column" => array("id" => "421", "name" => "element 1", "TYPE" => "1"),
    "subcolumns" => array(
        [0] => ("id" => "422", "name" => "element 2", "TYPE" => "2"),
        [1] => ("id" => "423", "name" => "element 3","TYPE" => "2")
     )
  )
  [424] => array(
    "column" => array("id" => "424", "name" => "element 4","TYPE" => "1"),
    "subcolumns" => array()
  )
)
```

Any ideas if I can accomplish this task with twig (it will be much better for me), if not, I am ok with PHP too. 
I have already tried to construct the HTML structure without changing the array but with no success.

I need to create columns and the "parent" should be the item with Type 1, all items with TYPE 2 should be childs of TYPE 1, in order to use jquery ui to sort them left and right.

Thank you!

Comment: Twig is a template engine, it's purpose to output data, not process it in anyway.

Comment: And second - what's the problem with iterating over array and rebuild it?

Comment: I don't know how to rebuild it.

Comment: Have you tried anything or just wating for codes?

Comment: I tried a lot in twig, that's why I first asked in twig and the in php. I come to ask here only when I can not find anything on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some code to start with:

```
$new_array = [];
$cur_id = 0;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($item['TYPE'] == 1) {
        $new_array[$item['id']] = [
            'column' => $item,
            'subcolumns' => [],
        ];
        $cur_id = $item['id'];
    } else {
        $new_array[$cur_id]['subcolumns'][] = $item;
    }
}
```